# Changing the height of div-element by sliding

Tags: jquery

I want to change the height of a div element by using the mouse Cursor by clicking on the bottom edge of the element and slide it to the new size. I would like to use JQuery.

Edit: Using JQuery UI resizable().

Comment: Please do not post any questions without proper researching on the website...!! Jquery has already given UI functionality.

Comment: ok. but how can i found jquery ui, if i don't know that this ist the right one what i'm searching. you know what i mean?

Comment: You should prepare a page using the code that i have highlighted in the grey area below, and then run it in the browser. To include jquery UI file, you just need to include [Jquery UI File](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js) in the header area of your website.

Comment: Thanks. I know that. I just meant - because of the downgrade - that my researching couldn't be good, because I just didn't know for what I am searching. Of course, if I know JQuery Ui, the answer is simple and everybody is downgrading my question...

Comment: It's good that you know jquery UI, but before posting the question, it is mentioned to have a detailed research study and mention all the details for the code work that is been done. And then if there is some issue in the code, then members can help you to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/), from this link

```
[<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<style>
#resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
#resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#resizable" ).resizable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
<h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to checkout jQuery UI Resizable:

http://jqueryui.com/resizable/